# Split Time into smaller parts

Tags: javascript, math, time

I have the duration of a video in seconds `634.567`! I have successfully converted this to HH:MM:SS:ms format using this code:

```
var pad = function(num, size) { return ('000' + num).slice(size * -1); },
time = parseFloat(timeInSeconds).toFixed(3),
hours = Math.floor(time / 60 / 60),
minutes = Math.floor(time / 60) % 60,
seconds = Math.floor(time - minutes * 60),
milliseconds = time.slice(-3);

return pad(hours, 2) + ':' + pad(minutes, 2) + ':' + pad(seconds, 2) + ',' + pad(milliseconds, 3);
```

This returns `"00:10:34,567"`

Now, I would like to split this time into intervals of 5 seconds. So, it becomes an JS array that looks like this

00.00.05, 000 | 00.00.10, 000 | 00.00.15, 000 | till the very last line in the array is 00:10:34,567 (so it's all in equal parts).

How do I split the time into smaller times then push it into an array?

Comment: Have your tried adding an extra line: seconds = Math.ceil(seconds/5)*5;

Comment: @jeff thanks for responding – what do you mean? I tried adding that but it just gave me 634!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For that, it would be probably better to work with the original time duration `timeInSeconds`, iterate in steps of 5 seconds and convert the corresponding value for each step, e.g.:

```
var pad = function(num, size) { return ('000' + num).slice(size * -1); };

function conv(t){
    var time = parseFloat(t).toFixed(3),
        hours = Math.floor(time / 60 / 60),
        minutes = Math.floor(time / 60) % 60,
        seconds = Math.floor(time - minutes * 60),
        milliseconds = time.slice(-3);

    return pad(hours, 2) + ':' + pad(minutes, 2) + ':' + pad(seconds, 2) + ',' + pad(milliseconds, 3);
}

var timeInSeconds = 634.567;

//required step
var delta = 5;

/*
  the condition (t < timeInSeconds + delta) in combination
  with Math.min(t, timeInSeconds) ensures that the for
  loop will consider the value timeInSeconds even if it
  is not divisible by delta
*/
var arr = [];
for(var t = 0; t < timeInSeconds + delta; t += delta){
    arr.push(conv(Math.min(t, timeInSeconds)));
}

console.log(arr);
```

So for example for `timeInSeconds = 11.0`, you would get:

```
[ '00:00:00,000', '00:00:05,000', '00:00:10,000', '00:00:11,000' ]
```

Comment: That did it! Thank you so much :)